# How to append REST call JSON response to jQuery datatables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm trying to display the REST call JSON response in jQuery [datatables](http://datatables.net).

Below is the JSON response I'm receiving.

```
{
    "artifact": [
        {
            "artifactId": "I8cc4a96ef69a11e08b448cf533780ea2",
            "batchId": "15581",
            "processId": "115458787"
        },
        {
            "artifactId": "e08b448cf533780ea2I8cc4a96ef69a11",
            "batchId": "14962",
            "processId": "787974254"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#artifacts").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true
            });
        });
        function submitForm()
        {
            $.getJSON('http://myurl.com/JerseySample/rest/search', function(data) {
                $.each(data.artifact, function(i,artifact){
                        $('#artifacts').datatable().fnAddData([
                                artifact.artifactId,
                                artifact.batchId,
                                artifact.processId ]
                                );
                });
             });
        }
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="searchform">
        <input class="searchfield" type="text" /> 
        <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" id="go" onclick="submitForm()" /> 

</form>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="demo_jui">
            <table id="artifacts" class="display">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Artifact Id</th>
                                <th>Batch Id</th>
                                <th>Legacy Id</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone provide an answer on why I am unable to load the JSON response into datatable? Is there a better approach to get this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing everything right, you're just doing one rookie mistake, and it's easy to miss.

When you do

```
$("#artifacts").dataTable();
```

You're creating a new datatable instance. Datatables returns the object instance (with API functions) on that call, but you're not storing that instance anywhere, therefor, you lose all reference to the datatable you just created.

To solve this, just add a reference to the datatable you create like so

```
var thisTable = $("#artifacts").dataTable(
    {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true
    }
);
```

and then reference it in your each function

```
$.each(data.artifact, function(i,artifact){
    thisTable.fnAddData(
        [
            artifact.artifactId,
            artifact.batchId,
            artifact.processId 
        ]
    );
 });
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bva8m/) to see it in action.

The [dynamically add new row](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/add_row.html) example on [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) is fairly poor, since it's doing an inline API call without the need to add a reference. It is better demonstrated on their following example on [multi filtering](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

You could also read about it on their [API documentation](http://datatables.net/api).
*Hint: it is demonstrated in the first row under `$`*

Comment: Thanks ShadowScripter! It worked. I read more in documentation and used serverside json response for datatable. But Pagination/Sort/Search is still an issue there. (Guessing, this must be because of sEcho thing.) Is there anything similar to datatables for REST xml responses- with Pagination/search capability? Thanks much! Help appreciated!

Comment: @Ajay There shouldn't be a problem with the pagination/sort/search. If you check out my example, add more than 10 rows and try sorting. It works exactly as it should. Ask a new question about that issue. Also, you should only use `bServerside` if you intend to do everything by yourself, including sorting/paging/searching. Having `bServerside` false by default is what you want in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I have raised a separate question for xml response. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585760/how-to-build-datatable-using-jquery-from-rest-xml-response)