# How to build datatable using jQuery from REST xml response?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a XML response from an Ajax REST call. Similar to the one below.

```
    <eventBlock>
        <event eventId="641">
            <processId>myprocess</processId>
            <batchId>15581</batchId>
            <user>Ajay</user>
            <participant>XYZ</participant>
            <activity>Jogging</activity>
            <note>Athletic</note>
            <createdOn>2011-11-22 00:00:00.0</createdOn>
            <createdBy>User5</createdBy>
        </event>
    </eventBlock>
```

My HTML:

```
    <form class="searchform" id="searchform" action="javascript: submitForm();">
     .....
    </form>
    <div id="UI">
        <table id="events" class="display">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>eventId</th>
                            <th>processId</th>
                            <th>batchId</th>
                            <th>user</th>
                            <th>participant</th>
                            <th>activity</th>
                            <th>note</th>
                            <th>createdOn</th>
                            <th>createdBy</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisTable;
thisTable = $("#events").dataTable(
    {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true
    }
);
        function addToTable(response){
            var $events = $(response).find("event");

            $events.each(function(index, event){
                var $event = $(event),
                    addData = [];

                addData.push($event.attr("eventId"));
                addData.push($event.children("processId").text());
                addData.push($event.children("batchId").text());
                addData.push($event.children("user").text());
                addData.push($event.children("participant").text());
                addData.push($event.children("activity").text());
                addData.push($event.children("note").text());
                addData.push($event.children("createdOn").text());
                addData.push($event.children("createdBy").text());

                thisTable.fnAddData(addData);
            });
        }

        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'../../data.xml',
                data:{
                    batchId:1234,
                    processId:afsfafgg  
                },
                type:"GET",
                success:addToTable
            });
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

When I hit the submit. I get below error on firebug. Can someone help me resolve this?

> oSettings is null
>   [Break On This Error]
>   var iRow = oSettings.aoData.length;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You *do* know about [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), right?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yep, I'm aware of that. But how do I make it work with datatables plugin? Any suggestions?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579935/how-to-append-rest-call-json-response-to-jquery-datatables) - I was working on JSON response. Was curious on handling XML response.Tried fnServerData with datatables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XML response is handled just like any other data type.
As long as you specify what type it should be expecting.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510995/parse-xml-response-with-jquery) shows you how to parse XML in JQuery. XML is handled like any other element.

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/KQmPb/)

```
$.ajax({
    url:"xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    type:"POST",
    success: function(response){
        var $events = $(response).find("event");

        $events.each(function(index, event){
            var $event = $(event),
            addData = [];

            $event.children().each(function(i, child){
                addData.push($(child).text());
            });

            dataTable.fnAddData(addData);
        });
    }
});
```

If you don't want to loop through all the children within each event, you can just assign them manually

```
$.ajax({
    url:"xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    type:"POST",
    success: function(response){
        var $events = $(response).find("event");

        $events.each(function(index, event){
            var $event = $(event),
            addData = [];

            addData.push($event.children("processId").text());
            addData.push($event.children("batchId").text());
            addData.push($event.children("user").text());
            addData.push($event.children("participant").text());
            addData.push($event.children("activity").text());
            addData.push($event.children("note").text());
            addData.push($event.children("createdOn").text());
            addData.push($event.children("createdBy").text();

            dataTable.fnAddData(addData);
        });
    }
});
```

Make sure that the array you send to fnAddData has as many items as the table has headers.

### Edit

After checking your HTML and Javascript, I can't reproduce the problem.

[Check out this test example](http://jsfiddle.net/jqbv2/)

I'm going to guess and say that there are more code, that you did not include, that's affecting the outcome.

I should probably point out that inline javascript functions are usually frowned upon in webdev circles. You should instead try to separate your javascript code from your html code, like in the latter example.

Use `$("#form").submit(function{...});` instead of inlining the function in your html.

Read up on [early event handler registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link2) vs [traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)

Comment: Thanks again for the response @ShadowScripter. I could get and parse XML data. But at fnAddData, I get this error: oSettings is null
var iRow = oSettings.aoData.length;.

Comment: @Ajay In my example I loop through each child node from the XML, and I also have each table header for each node. If the corresponding column lengths do not max, datatables will throw that error. Make sure you're adding as many rows as the datatable has headers. Since my example works just fine, it is most likely a problem on your end. How many table headers do you have, and which nodes do you want to display on the table?

Comment: Thanks. I double checked the number of nodes and the headers. I have 9 headers and I'm passing 9 variables inside fnAddData. I could see all the 9 variables being assigned values in Firebug console. Thanks much.

Comment: @Ajay I updated my answer to show you how to assign values manually. If you think my answer was satisfactory, please mark as answered. :)

Comment: Thanks again. No luck this time too. I am still getting the oSettings is null error @ var iRow = oSettings.aoData.length; addData is of length 9 and I have 9 <th> tags. :(

Comment: @Ajay Could you edit your post and add the HTML/Javascript that's giving you the error?

Comment: Thanks ShadwoScripter. I just added `thisTable.fnAddData(addData, false);` and `thisTable.fnDraw();` after the loop.

Comment: @ShadowScripter, I implemented your fiddle code in my application with some modification, I'm not getting any error, but the problem is, it adds all the data to first row instead of adding it to the next row.. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The REST is likely cross domain, in which case you would need to create a proxy on your server to retrieve the XML .  Proxy becomes your ajax url.

If your objective is to create a "read only" table you could simply print the xml as output to an ajax request and parse output to a table yourself in ajax sucecss callback prior to calling datatables.

If you need edit capability and want the datasource passed directly to datatables plugin, you would need to parse xml server side to json.

How you handle this all depends on your needs. Proxy is relatively easy to set up either way.

If REST serves JSONP, can bypass the proxy

EDIT. Another approach is to use a service like Yahoo YQL as proxy. Can set that up in minutes